# Having trouble copying conda environment folder containing same word (different case) files with symbolic links in terminfo subdirectory

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, cp, conda, case-insensitive

I am using WSL1.

- I am trying to save a copy of my ~./miniconda/envs folder to the desktop using `cp`.
- I keep getting errors like `cp: cannot create regular file './envs/py_env/share/terminfo/h/hp2621a': File exists`
- The problem is that there are 2 files with the same name but different case.  For example, `hp2621a` and `hp2621A`.

---

Example:

Original Folder: `hp2621a`, `hp2621A`, `etc`

Using `cp` I get:

- New Folder: `hp2621A`, `etc`
- Missing:  `hp2621a`

---

- Some of the subdirectories of `py_env/share` and `py_env/lib` also have a similar problem (`A` and `a` seemed to conflict)
- I was able to solve some of these errors by changing the name of a directory from `A` to `A_1`.

Comment: The problem is likely that your *Windows* desktop is on a filesystem that doesn't distinguish letter case by default - see for example [Differences between Windows and Linux case sensitivity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/case-sensitivity#differences-between-windows-and-linux-case-sensitivity)

Comment: Why are you making the copy in the first place? Is it for backing up? If so, why not use a tar archive?

Comment: I wanted to make a copy for back up. Tar archives would have been a better option. @steeldriver was saying that the files are set as case insensitive on my desktop. fsutil query returns: Case sensitive attribute on directory C:\Users\[myusername]\desktop\envs is disabled. I can change the sensitivity.

Comment: Sorry, wrote up the answer before I noticed that you'd already solved this in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

From the comments, it looks like you've found this already -- There's some [good documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/case-sensitivity) on why this is happening and how to handle it.

By default, folders on Windows NTFS drives are case-insensitive; `A` and `a` are the same filename.  However, for some time now (since 2018) Windows has the ability to specify case-sensitivity on a directory-by-directory (and inheritable) basis.  To do so:

- The directory where you place these files will need to be empty to start with.  Either remove everything from the existing directory or create a new empty directory on the desktop.  We'll assume the name of this directory is `$env:USERPROFILE\Desktop\env`.
- From PowerShell, run:

  ```
  fsutil.exe file setCaseSensitiveInfo $env:USERPROFILE\Desktop\env enable
  ```

That should be all that is needed for your `cp` command to work properly.  If not, though, see the doc page for some more options and details.